# Update Listbox after inserting a row in database

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, listbox, bindingsource

I have a listbox which has a bindingsource which connects to access database.  have following code which creates and adds new line to my access database and to datagrid view but changes are not updating in the listbox.

```
    Dim drv As DataRowView = DirectCast(EQtblBindingSource.AddNew(), DataRowView)

    drv.BeginEdit()

    drv.Row.BeginEdit()

    drv.Row("eiD") = "SS"
    drv.Row("EQ_NAME") = "DUMMY"

    drv.Row.EndEdit()

    drv.DataView.Table.Rows.Add(drv.Row)
    EQ_tblTableAdapter.Update(EQDATADataSet.EQ_tbl)                
    EQtblBindingSource.ResetBindings(True)
```

Is there a way to reflect changes immediately after i add a new row? resetbindings seems not working or another option to reload or refresh my listbox. Any idea please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the DataSource for your listbox is set to the bindingsource.

Your code can be simplified to this:

```
   With EQtblBindingSource
        .AddNew()
        DirectCast(.Current, DataRowView)("eiD") = "SS"
        DirectCast(.Current, DataRowView)("EQ_NAME") = "DUMMY"
        .EndEdit()
    End With
    EQ_tblTableAdapter.Update(EQDATADataSet.EQ_tbl)
```

Comment: Hi, this works when adding new record just through button.. for example if i have another form (child form) above the listbox which contains datagridview then it updates the datagrid view ..not the listbox in the parent form. Any idea how to push the change to listbox?

Comment: Hi Shan, I think you should create a new question and include source code you are using and what you want to do